# Show Div when Grid Item is Clicked - Javascript not Updating Panel

Tags: asp.net

On one aspx page I have a GridView that has a list of Thingys that are loaded from db. This is placed in one div.

In another Div with display=none I have the form to add a new thingy.

I also have a link [add new thingy] that hides the gridview div and shows the content of the form.

I am using JS methods to hide and show the Divs.

Now in the grid the first column is also a link that I want to load the form with the Thingy info without postback.

Currently the problem is that if I use the Grid's OnRowCommand I get a postback.

1) how can I remove that postback and load the form in the second Div

2) a similar issue is on save form, I can switch back to the gridview div using js really quickly but how do I reload the grid with the newly saved Thingies.

I am open to a completely different approach if it solves the issue. I chose this approach over the much easier UpdatePanel because its much faster to switch between the contents without a postback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking to do is use Ajax on this page, here is what you need to have in place to do that:

- Code behind create functions with the `[WebMethod]` Attribute.  These functions will be called by JavaScript to handle the server side processing (getting updated information, creating new items, etc.)
- Hava a ScriptManager control on the .aspx page that has `EnabledPageMethods="True"`
- Create JavaScript to populate the controls and send requests to the code behind using Ajax.  I would look into the jQuery and Knockout Frameworks if I where you.

Resources:

- [Asp.net call C# method from Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372532/asp-net-call-c-sharp-method-from-ajax)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/)